# Transfer files to Rook Ceph

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, rook-storage

I have a Harbor docker deployment with images stored under `/data/registry`. I also have a K8s cluster with a harbor Helm chart deployed on it. I am using rook-ceph as my registry storage solution. How can I transfer the files under `/data/registry` into my rook-ceph persistent volume?

Comment: Just so that I understand: you want to synchronize your data? Sounds like a Very Bad Idea™  to me, since the index will not work: the repository URL is part of the fully qualified image name.

Answer (score 0):

If the versions of your Harbor instances are the same, you can try to replicate your data over to your k8s Harbor instance. See [docs](https://goharbor.io/docs/2.5.0/administration/configuring-replication/) for more info. Member information is not replicated.